# Why won't I get any results when I try to pull customers ordering from different states?

Tags: sql

Here's the question:

List the order number, the order date, the customer number, the customer name (first and last), 
-- the customer state, and the shipping state (OrdState) in which the customer state differs from shipping state.

Here's my code:

```
SELECT Orders.OrdNo, OrdDate, Customer.CustNo, CustFirstName, CustLastName, 
CustState, OrdState

FROM Orders, Customer

WHERE Orders.OrdNo = Customer.CustNo AND

OrdState <> CustState
```

Yet when I run it, it doesn't give me any results, even though I can clearly look at the data table provided and see that I should get at least some results popping up. Any ideas?

Comment: Hint:  Explicit `JOIN` syntax.  It is the 21st Century.

Comment: `Orders.OrdNo = Customer.CustNo`: typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have Order Number equal to Customer Number...

```
Orders.OrdNo = Customer.CustNo
```

Presumably (guessing as I can't see the schema) it should be

```
Orders.CustNo = Customer.CustNo
```

Also as pointed out in the comments - you should be explicit in your joins (and probably use aliases);

```
SELECT o.OrdNo, OrdDate, c.CustNo, CustFirstName, CustLastName, 
CustState, OrdState    
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN Customer c
    ON o.OrdNo = c.CustNo
WHERE     
    o.OrdState <> c.CustState
```